# Spring MVC - duplicate values when editing an existing object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem when I want to edit an existing user object in my application. First of all, I have a controller class which provides the following methods:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String eMail = request.getParameter("email");
    User user = userDao.findUserByEMail(eMail);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");
    model.addObject("user", user);
    return model;
}

@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEditUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println(user);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }

    userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

I have two JSP files. The first one shows all my users (stored in a database) and provides the opportunity to edit an existing user (same JSP for adding a new user).

> UserList.jsp

```
<div align="center">
    <h1>Users List</h1>
    <h2>
        <a href="<c:url value='/new'/>">New User</a>
    </h2>

    <table border="1">
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Birthdate</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
        <th>Actions</th>

        <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td>${user.forename}</td>
                <td>${user.surname}</td> 
                <td>${user.birthdate}</td>
                <td>${user.email}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url  value='/edit?email=${user.email}'/>">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="<c:url  value='/delete?email=${user.email}'/>">Delete</a>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

> UserForm.jsp

```
<div align="center">
    <h1>New/Edit User</h1>
    <table>
        <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="user">
            <form:hidden path="id" id="id" />
            <tr>
                <td>Forename:</td>
                <td><form:input path="forename" id="forename" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Surname:</td>
                <td><form:input path="surname" id="surname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Birthdate:</td>
                <td><form:input path="birthdate" id="birthdate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-Mail:</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" id="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
                    value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </form:form>
    </table>
</div>

<br />
<br /> Go back to
<a href="<c:url  value='/listUsers' />">List of all users</a>
```

After editing a user, the `mail` attribute of the user contains the same value a second time and I don't know why. For example, I want to change the `surname` of the user from `User` to `UserA` and I got the error message:

> org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>
> Field error in object 'user' on field 'email': rejected value
>   [test@user.com,test@user.com]; codes
>   [Email.user.email,Email.email,Email.java.lang.String,Email]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [user.email,email]; arguments []; default message
>   [email],[Ljavax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag;@653e5537,.*];
>   default message [Please provide a valid email address]

I have no idea why it happens and I would be pleased if you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `editUser` method is called when the URL `/edit?email=...` is invoked.  The method loads the view defined in the file `UserForm.jsp`.  The JSP file contains an HTML `form` tag but does not set the `action` attribute of the form tag.  Therefore, the form is submitted to the same URL that loaded the form (which is `/edit?email=...`).

The form in turn contains a field named `email`.  This field gets submitted with the form.  This is why you get the same email address in the model object twice.

If you do not want the email address to be editable, you can use a text label instead of an `input` form field.  If you want the email address to be editable, change the name of the URL parameter to something other than `email`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changed `/edit?email=...` to `/edit?usermail=...` and it works fine for me. You helped me a lot.